# Which STIDs are supported by PostGIS st_transform function

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I'm developing rest api (with postgresql data base and postgis) method to get point in requested `srid`.
There's a method in Postgis which is transforming geometry from current `srid` to another.

```
geometry ST_Transform(geometry g1, integer srid);
```

https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Transform.html

So I want to know which `SRIDs` are supported by the method? The official documentation doesn't provide answer.

Comment: https://postgis.net/docs/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#spatial_ref_sys ?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name looks like words of true. post it like an answer and I'll select it as correct. thanks.